# How to update variable within a while loop?

Tags: python

I update the variable directly in the database (manually). But, the code in the `while` loop never updates the variable because it is in a loop, I would like to know what I should do to get the new value.

Maybe exit the loop and reopen it? I tried with `break`, but it closes the script.

```
import sqlite3

def read_data(data, table):
    con = sqlite3.connect("settings.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    read_data.row = cur.execute(f"SELECT {data} FROM {table}").fetchall()[0][0]

read_data("data", "eyes")
eyes = read_data.row

while True:
    read_data("data", "eyes")
    eyes_loop = read_data.row

    if eyes_loop != eyes:
        print("Eyes changed")
        break

    else:
        print("Eyes not changed")
        continue
```

Comment: `return` the data from your function.

Comment: When I put the `return eyes` it exits the program, as if it were a break.

Comment: [What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855)

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple things not quite right:

1. You should close your connection if you establish it inside a function.
2. You should return values instead of overwriting them outside the scope. Nasty side effects can occur.

```
import sqlite3

def read_data(data, table):
    con = sqlite3.connect("settings.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    data = cur.execute(f"SELECT {data} FROM {table}").fetchall()[0][0]
    con.close()
    return data


eyes = read_data("data", "eyes")

while True:
    eyes_loop = read_data("data", "eyes")

    if eyes_loop != eyes:
        print("Eyes changed")
        break

    else:
        print("Eyes not changed")
        continue
```

Comment: It doesn't work, inside the loop while "Eyes" is the same. I want "Eyes" to change if I change it in the database.

Comment: Please check if read_data returns a "fitting" value and not `None` for example. Maybe print the output or use the debugger for this.  If the correct value is returned we can continue debugging. @principemestizo3

Comment: I honestly don't understand.

Comment: In your code `print(eyes)`

Comment: I do it, if in the db I have "1", 1 comes out in the loop, if I change it in the db to 0, it does not change in the loop to 0.

Comment: What does it say if you run this code and write `print(eyes)` after `eyes = read_data("data", "eyes")` but before the while-loop?

Comment: The same appears, only once. The number 1, what should come out. The problem is that inside it does not change, as I mentioned.

Comment: Is your database cached in any way?

Comment: Are you printing eyes or eyes_loop in the loop?

Answer (score -1):

The function you are using takes time to connect with database and send data back and forth. This code runs asynchronously so the loop runs and it runs past the `read_data()` to avoid this use `async/await`.